# Missing Personal site url in user profile properties after editing filters in ups connection - mysite - powershell

Tags: user-profile, my-site, user, user-profile-property

Something strange has happend in my environment. I've pre-populated 1500 user profiles and everything was ok. After some changes with the connections filters in user profile synchronization connection it seams that every users has got their personal site url deleted in their user properties.

**Question 1:** 
Is there a way to update every user profile with their "Personal site" url?  (timerjob / cleanup .. )

I'm trying to run a script to update every user profile but when I try to update the field I get that the property are "read-only".

```
foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)
{

    $DisplayName = $profile.DisplayName
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value

        Try
            #$time = Get-Date -Format HH:mm:ss
            if($profile.PersonalSite -eq $Null)
            {
                $person = $AccountName.Substring(7)
                $personalSite = Get-SPSite $profilFullURL"/personal/"$person

                if($personalSite)
                {
                    Write-Host $time" $x  updating personal site in profile:"$person -NoNewline
                    $profile.PersonalSite = $personalSite.Url
                    $profile.Commit()
                    Write-Host " Done" -ForegroundColor Green
                    $x++
                }
```

**Question 2:**
how do I update personalsite ? (read-only)

Comment: Try to run the script as the farm admin on the server.

Comment: I usually run script as sync user. but I tried with sp_farm and it didn't work

Comment: Aside from the blank URL are you seeing some behavior that this is impacting? Usually the mysite link will resolve itself when the user is redirected. What is the problem you face?

Comment: No strange behavior right now.. But its kind of strange and makes me nervous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for updating the field.. Had to use

```
$profile["PersonalSpace"].Value = "/personal/"+$person
```

**Remember to have a url that starts with "/personal/"**